# Remove decimal Java variable

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot method in which I have a variable to calculate the vacation days (VACATION_DAYS_GEN_DAILY), the problem is that when I show them in the front it jumps with all the decimals. I need to know how I can remove those tell them.

```
private static final double VACATION_DAYS_GEN_DAILY = 22.0 * 4 / (365 * 4 + 1);

public EmployeeDashboardDto getEmployeeDashboardYearDto(Integer year, Integer employeeId) throws QOException {

LocalDate fromDate = LocalDate.of(year, 1, 1);
LocalDate toDate = LocalDate.of(year, 12, 31);

double leftVacationDays;
double vacationsPerWorkedDays = 0;
int pastVacations = 0;

EmployeeView emp = employeeService.getById(employeeId).getBean();

if (fromDate.isBefore(toDate)) {
        vacationsPerWorkedDays = (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(fromDate, toDate) - AbsenceDays + 1)
        * VACATION_DAYS_GEN_DAILY;
}

leftVacationDays = emp.getCummulatedVacationDays() + vacationsPerWorkedDays;
employeeDashboardDto.setLeftVacationDays(leftVacationDays);

return employeeDashboardDto;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-round-decimal-number) maybe helpful or you can use this:

```
double roundOff = Math.round(VACATION_DAYS_GEN_DAILY * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

the output:

```
21.98
```